# Webpack dependencies between external files

Tags: webpack

I'm looking at migrating a requirejs project to webpack but I've run into a problem. Requirejs shims allow me to express dependencies between external (non AMD) libraries e.g.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        foundation: '../bower_components/foundation/js/foundation'
    },
    shim: {
        "foundation": ['jquery']
    }
}

require(['foundation'], function(f, app) {
    // use foundation (jquery also resolved)
});
```

How can I achieve something similar with webpack? All the examples I have seen talk about a webpack module (commonjs or AMD) depending on external libraries but I can't find anything about wiring up the dependencies between external libaries.

Comment: In the end I had to go back to requirejs. It seems webpack works fine if you are dealing with AMD or CommonJS modules but it breaks if you need to express dependencies between non module files

Answer (score 0):

You can try with exports and imports loader. We used it for lib like Ember. It should look like something :

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /foundation.js$/,
        loader: 'exports?foundation!imports?jquery'
      }]
}
```